# Websphere server 8.5 not starting

Tags: webserver, websphere, websphere-8, rad

When I try to start the webshere server 8.5, I get the following error:

```
    20-05-26 22:49:12:697 EDT] 000000a7 UserRegistryI E   SECJ0330E: Le fichier d'implémentation du registre com.vmd.common.test.userregistry.DummyVmdUserRegistry ne peut pas être chargé en raison de l'exception suivante java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vmd.common.test.userregistry.DummyVmdUserRegistry
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.createCustomImplInstance(UserRegistryImpl.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.initialize(UserRegistryImpl.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.do_createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:729)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getUserRegistryImpl(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:671)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.server.SecurityServerImpl.getRegistryImpl(SecurityServerImpl.java:659)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.getUserRegistry(LTPAServerObject.java:2628)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.authenticate(LTPAServerObject.java:986)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule.login(ltpaLoginModule.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:796)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:211)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:710)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:708)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:707)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:604)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.JaasLoginHelper.jaas_login(JaasLoginHelper.java:357)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:4759)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:4385)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:4381)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3973)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.util.SecurityHelper.authenticate(SecurityHelper.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.basicAuth(CallRouter.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)

[20-05-26 22:49:12:697 EDT] 000000a7 UserRegistryC E   SECJ0281E: Erreur de création de l'objet registre d'utilisateurs. L'exception est java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vmd.common.test.userregistry.DummyVmdUserRegistry
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.createCustomImplInstance(UserRegistryImpl.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.initialize(UserRegistryImpl.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.do_createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:729)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.createRegistryObjects(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.UserRegistryConfigImpl.getUserRegistryImpl(UserRegistryConfigImpl.java:671)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.server.SecurityServerImpl.getRegistryImpl(SecurityServerImpl.java:659)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.getUserRegistry(LTPAServerObject.java:2628)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.authenticate(LTPAServerObject.java:986)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule.login(ltpaLoginModule.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:796)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:211)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:710)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:708)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:707)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:604)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.JaasLoginHelper.jaas_login(JaasLoginHelper.java:357)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:4759)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:4385)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:4381)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3973)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.util.SecurityHelper.authenticate(SecurityHelper.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.basicAuth(CallRouter.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
.
[20-05-26 22:49:12:698 EDT] 000000a7 RoleBasedAuth A   SECJ0305I: Echec du contrôle d'autorisation basée sur le rôle pour admin-authz opérations Server : getState.  L'utilisateur UNAUTHENTICATED (ID unique : UNAUTHENTICATED) n'a pas reçu un des rôles requis suivants : deployer, operator, configurator, monitor, administrator, adminsecuritymanager, auditor.
```

I looked for a solution in IBM pages and over the net but I am not able to find a solution for now,
do you have any suggestion to resolve this please ?

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to implement your custom user registry by class `com.vmd.common.test.userregistry.DummyVmdUserRegistry`, which you didnt describe in the question, you have to put that class to the `AppServer\lib\ext` folder, as it clearly cannot be found right now by server infrastructrue.

Comment: that's right can you put it as an answer please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to implement your custom user registry by class `com.vmd.common.test.userregistry.DummyVmdUserRegistry`, which you didn't describe in the question, you have to put that class to the `AppServer\lib\ext` folder, as it clearly cannot be found right now by server infrastructure.